# Странные символы в коде сайта

Tags: unicode

Через определённое время творится хаос в чате, когда появляется данный код, который виден в инспекторе в браузере firefox. Скрин прикрепляю. Пытаюсь его скопировать, но при редактировании отображает нормальный код прямо в инспекторе. Если просто смотреть, то, как на скрине. Подскажите куда копать и что за код это? Проблемы такой нету на Chrome браузере, только Firefox. Сайт использует кодировку windows-1251.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваша проблема в том что "сайт использует кодировку 1251". Как только сайт будет переведен в нормальную(utf8/unicode) - просмотр через консоль станет показывать вредоносный код - всегда, а не иногда.

Comment: Слишком много времени нужно, чтобы перевести сайт в UTF-8. Сам скрипт староват для этого. Как можно увидеть код нормально с текущей кодировкой? Если скопировать код или сохранить страницу, код будет нормальный.

Comment: Подскажите хотя бы куда рыть? И какой код символов, которые видны.